# How do I disable the transfer confirmation?

Tags: fiz

I have just started a NG+ save, and every time I brew a batch and try to store it for later, I get an annoying request to confirm, which AFAIK didn’t happen in the original save.

[image]

How do I get rid of it?  I don’t need a confirmation here!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a force quit of the app and reopening it has solved the issue... Cool.